# Prove that a series converges (under the certain terms)

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Let $ \left(a_{k}\right)_{k=1}^{\infty} $ be a positive nonzero sequence, and assume that for any $ k \in \mathbb{N} $ it follows that $ a_{k}\cdot a_{k+2}<a_{k+1}^{2} $ and that $ a_1<a_2 $ .

Prove that the series $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k} $ converges.

To be honese, I have no idea how the given details helps me to say something about convergence/divergence.

Any idea would help.

Comment: Which series?${}$

Comment: I think the hypothesis should be $a_2 < a_1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer as the question appeared in the source is $ a_1<a_2 $

Comment: It's probably a typo. For $a_1 < a_2$ you can consider $a_k = k$ to have a divergent series.

Comment: @Daniel Fishcher I see. For $ a_2<a_1 $ Its easy question, thanks.